# Missing artifact org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:pom:2.4.1 in central

Tags: spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

I've tried to build a springboot project with thymeleaf and layout templating. For this I've included spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf and thymeleaf-layout-dialect in my pom.xml. But when I try to run I get the errors

```
Could not find artifact org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:pom:2.4.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

and

```
Could not find artifact org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:pom:2.4.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

I'm useing the newest versions of all dependencies and searched at google, but didn't find any answers. So can anybody tell me where this error comes from and how to solve it? Would be very thankful.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>lucis</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>lucis</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <springboot.version>2.2.5.RELEASE</springboot.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>2.4.1</thymeleaf.version>
    <mysql.version>8.0.19</mysql.version>
    <bootstrap.version>4.4.1</bootstrap.version>
    <jquery.version>3.4.1</jquery.version>
    <locator.version>0.39</locator.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>${bootstrap.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>${jquery.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        <version>${locator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>-->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Remove the version properties from the dependencies and remove `thymeleaf.version` property. and `spring-boot.version`. The parent already manages those.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Someone told me it is always better to add versions to all dependencies, so I thougth it would be necessary. Thanks for help

Comment: Not if you are using the starters. And with the `thymeleaf.version` property you are also overriding the thymeleaf managed version for spring boot.